# Converting Vertx Future<T> To RX Observable<Optional<T>>

Tags: observable, rx-java, future, vert.x

I need to provide some util function that converts a Vertx `Future<T>` to Rx `Observable<Optional<T>>` for backwards compatibility.

Should this be good enough?

```
Observable.fromCompletionStage(future.toCompletionStage());
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because `Observable.fromCompletionStage` returns `Observable<T>`, not `Observable<Optional<T>>`.

You must create the `Optional` from the future result with `ofNullable`:

```
Observable.fromCompletionStage(future.map(Optional::ofNullable).toCompletionStage());
```